# Swift: NSArray to Set?

Tags: swift, set, nsarray

I am trying to convert an `NSArray` to a Swift `Set`.

Not having much luck.

What is the proper way to do so?

For example if I have an `NSArray` of numbers:

```
@[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

How do I create a Swift `Set` from that `NSArray`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you *know for sure* that the `NSArray` contains only number objects
then you can convert it to an Swift array of `Int` (or `Double` or
`NSNumber`, depending on your needs) and create a set from that:

```
let nsArray = NSArray(array: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
let set = Set(nsArray as! [Int])
```

If that is not guaranteed, use an optional cast:

```
if let set = (nsArray as? [Int]).map(Set.init) {
    print(set)
} else {
    // not an array of numbers
}
```

Another variant (motivated by @JAL's comments):

```
let set = Set(nsArray.flatMap { $0 as? Int })
// Swift 4.1 and later:
let set = Set(nsArray.compactMap { $0 as? Int })
```

This gives a set of all `NSArray` elements which are convertible
to `Int`, and silently ignores all other elements.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something like: `var mySet = Set<Int>(); mySet.insert(nsArray.map { $0 })`?  I'm getting an "Ambiguous reference to member 'map'" error

Comment: @JAL: `insert()` adds a single element, perhaps you meant `unionInPlace()`. But for some reason, `mySet.unionInPlace(nsArray.map { $0 })` does not compile, you need an explicit cast `mySet.unionInPlace(nsArray.map { $0 as! Int })`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  `unionInPlace` is very cool, I didn't realize there was a function that takes in a `SequenceType` like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're working with `Int`s, you could always iterate through your array and manually add each element to a `Set<Int>`:

```
let theArray = NSArray(array: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

var theSet = Set<Int>()

for number in (theArray as? [Int])! {
    theSet.insert(number)
}

print(theSet) // "[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 8]\n"
```

I'm trying to work out a more elegant solution with `map`, I'll update this answer as I make more progress.

Thanks to MartinR's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071099/swift-nsarray-to-set/34072646?noredirect=1#comment55900237_34072646) to use `unionInPlace` (which takes in the `SequenceType` returned from `map`) instead of `insert` on the `Set`, this can be accomplished like so:

```
let theArray = NSArray(array: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
var mySet = Set<Int>()
mySet.unionInPlace(theArray.map { $0 as! Int })
```

Note that this may not be the safest solution due to the explicit cast to `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

let nsarr: NSArray = NSArray(array: [1,2,3,4,5])
var set: Set<Int>
guard let arr = nsarr as? Array<Int>  else {
    exit(-1)
}
set = Set(arr)
print(set.dynamicType)
dump(set)
/*
Set<Int>
▿ 5 members
  - [0]: 5
  - [1]: 2
  - [2]: 3
  - [3]: 1
  - [4]: 4
*/
```

with help of free bridging, it should be easy ...

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
var set = Set(array)
```